# wpf toolkit colorpicker

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, wpftoolkit

Does anyone have a clue how to use this?  The documentation as usual is worthless.

What event do I need to fire to grab the color that is selected and then how do I get the color that I selected?  anyone!  I spent about 4 hours on Google and give up.

What I want to do is select text, then click the color-picker in order to change the color of the selected text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedColorChanged` is the Event and `SelectedColor` is what you need to grab the color.

Comment: @BalaR I'm getting following error on `myRichTxtBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, myColorPicker.SelectedColor);`. The **Error**: >>'Color' parameter type is not valid for formatting property 'Foreground'. How do we resolve this, any suggestions?